# AngularJS : How to access the directive's scope in transcluded content?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have trouble getting my transcluding directive to work. I want to do the following: Create a directive that outputs a list where the content of each item is defined by transcluded content. E.g:

```
<op-list items="myItems">
  <span class="item">{{item.title}}</span>
</op-list>
```

so I would use ng-repeat inside op-list's template and must be able to access the scope created by ng-repeat inside the transcluded content.

This is what I've done so far:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myModel = {
        name: 'Superhero',
        items: [{
            title: 'item 1'
        }, {
            title: 'item 2'
        }]
    };
}]);

myApp.directive('opList', function () {

    return {
        template: '<div>' +
            '<div>items ({{items.length}}):</div>' +
            '<div ng-transclude ng-repeat="item in items"></div>' +
            '</div>',
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            items: '='
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">
  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div>Hello, {{myModel.name}}!</div>
    <op-list items="myModel.items"> 
        <span>title: {{item.title}}|{{$scope}}|{{scope}}|{{items}}</span>
    </op-list>
</div>
  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works:

```
myApp.directive('opList', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    return {
        template: '<div>' +
            '<div>items ({{model.items.length}}):</div>' +
            '<ng-transclude ng-repeat="item in model.items"></ng-transclude>' +
            '</div>',
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            items: '='
        }
    };
}]);
```

If it doesn't then try to inspect $scope in console and see if you're able to access your model.

Comment: just adding `$scope` to the directive? Did that, doesn't work, see edited question.

Comment: Were you able to check the $scope object in console? Do you see anything there?

Comment: Corrected my injection mechanism. I just want to be sure that $scope is available. If yes then we can go on to the problem of finding our model in the scope.

Comment: Now there is an error, try to run the snippet in my question to see it. I think the scope is not yet available. We would have to use the link function to access it.

Comment: Bad mistake... update the snippet. I see the object is accessible. Now need to figure out when it's not working with ng-repeat...

Comment: Could you pass the inner content as string? The same way you're passing items.

Comment: Just realized that you can use the transcludeFn to do this. Go through the link function definition on this page for transcludeFn details: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile